# How to sort a .json file based on a subkey value in Perl

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon's AWS command-line tool to extract all instances that we have running. This produces a .json file with (modified) the following format:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "8172695814",
            "ReservationId": "q-9d77c34a",
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    ...
                    "LaunchTime": "2014-08-14T11:37:29.000Z",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Value": "Server 5",
                            "Key": "Name"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    ...
```

I want to use this output as the source for a dashboard-like application, built in Perl. My problem is that the server list in the .json file is not sorted the way I want: I would like to see them ordered by Tag name (the values behind Tags-Value). So in the example above, any Server 1 to 4 should be above the Server 5, and all others below.

(edited) I can loop throught the values in order to show them in the dashboard like this:

```
foreach my $instance_list (@instances) {
        foreach my $instance (@$instance_list){
                if ( $$instance{'Instances'}[0]{'State'}{'Name'} !~ m/terminated/io ) {
                        if ( $$instance{'Instances'}[0]{'Tags'}[0]{'Value'} =~ m/Server.*/o ) {
                        ...
```

But now the challenge is to get the elements sorted in the proer order. Can anyone tell me on how this can be done in Perl? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is sorting in Perl, I can't get it sorted on the Nth element properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. The probles was that the Reservations element was there double, so I needed to fetch the first element to work with. This is what it is like now:

```
@{$instances[0]} = sort { $a->{'Instances'}[0]{'Tags'}[0]{'Value'} cmp $b->{'Instances'}[0]{'Tags'}[0]{'Value'} } @{$instances_unsorted[0]};
```

Thank for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom sort method with perl : `@sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @list;`

If you play this example:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @servers = ( 
    { name => "server1", launchtime => "2014-08-14T11:37:29.000Z" },
    { name => "server2", launchtime => "2014-08-15T11:37:29.000Z" },
    { name => "server5", launchtime => "2014-08-16T11:37:29.000Z" },
    { name => "server4", launchtime => "2014-08-17T11:37:29.000Z" },
    { name => "server3", launchtime => "2014-08-12T11:37:29.000Z" },
 );

print Dumper( \@servers);


my @default_sorted = sort @servers;

my @custom_sorted = sort {$a->{name} cmp $b->{name}} @servers;
```

The result will be:

- default_sorted => server5, 4, 3, 1, 2 *(because of the lauchtime
  probaly)*
- custom_sorted => server1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: I found that one, but it looks you can only sort on one level deep. I want it sorted on {Reservations}[x]{'Instances'}[0]{'Tags'}[0]{'Value'}.

Comment: @cootje As long as you're passing sort a list, you can compare whatever deep level keys that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $servers = {
  Reservations => [ {
    Something => 'foo',
    Instances => [ {
      Tags => [ {
        Value => 1,
        Key   => 'Name',
      } ],
    } ],
  }, {
    Something => 'bar',
    Instances => [ {
      Tags => [ {
        Value => 0,
        Key   => 'Name',
      } ],
    } ],
  } ],
};

foreach (sort { $a->{Instances}[0]{Tags}[0]{Value} <=>
                $b->{Instances}[0]{Tags}[0]{Value} }
                  @{$servers->{Reservations}}) {
  say $_->{Something};
}
```

Prints 'bar' followed by 'foo' - which is the correct order.